# What charset SHOULD be used for a Location: header in a 301 response?

Tags: encoding, httpwebrequest, location, httpwebresponse, rfc

Trying to consume the URI `cot.ag/o1LnfW` from .NET with the HttpWebRequest, I get the 301 Moved response, the response header Location has a (incorrect) value of:

`http://www.joycemeyer.org/BroadcastHome.aspx?video=Living_Beyond_Your_Feelings_â_Pt_1&utm_source=Twitter&utm_campaign=EEL&utm_medium=post&utm_term=September29&utm_content=post`

From Fiddler, I get the (correct) Location header value:

`http://www.joycemeyer.org/BroadcastHome.aspx?video=Living_Beyond_Your_Feelings_–_Pt_1&utm_source=Twitter&utm_campaign=EEL&utm_medium=post&utm_term=September29&utm_content=post`

Noted the difference where the – occurs in the Fiddler URL. In the case of Fiddler, the bytes are E2 80 93.  In the case of .Net, the bytes are E2 3F 3F. This results in an incorrect header interpretation, with subsequent failure to follow the redirection.

I think this is a .NET framework bug, but I have no idea what the RFCs say it SHOULD sent as. Should I report this as a bug to Microsoft, or is this a failure by bit.ly in serving the headers in the wrong code-page?

Comment: Note that â is the octet E2 from [IEC-8859-1][1] and in [UTF-8][2] that's the start of a 3-byte (16-bit) encoding of the hyphen.  The 3F 3F are the replacement character mappings of the 80 and 93 (the last two encoded UTF-8 bytes).

Thus, it appears that Edward is right, this is a conformant implemenetation of [RFC 2616][3], if not a very forgiving one.

[1]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1
[2]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
[3]http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: Just a long-ago follow-up, bit.ly is now feeding the Location: header with % encoded characters per RFC1630.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) specifies that the `Location` header should contain a URI as defined by [RFC 1630](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1630.txt), which requires a URI be 7-bit clean ASCII with any special characters URL encoded.

In other words, the server is delivering the URI incorrectly and should be escaping it.

Comment: Bummer that Fiddler gets it right (as does Chrome, IE9), but .Net framework doesn't. Personally I'd call out .Net...

Comment: Well, it may depend on your default charset - .NET wouldn't have a basis for knowing what those characters are and is probably using your default code page...  which, for US users, is CP 1252 (which is probably a bad guess.)  If you change your code page to UTF-8 does the behavior change?

Comment: I've looked in the .Net source. Their response header processing is handled by a explicit and internal ASCII-only Encoding. I can't affect that code page AT ALL. They document this as being done for performance, but it seems that OTHER implementations assume UTF-8 as the code page headers are coming back in (or sniffing, or assuming the Content-Type gives the codepage--which it doesn't).

Comment: Here's the source commed from WebHeaderCollection.cs in the debugging sources:

        // we use this static class as a helper class to encode/decode HTTP headers.
        // what we need is a 1-1 correspondence between a char in the range U+0000-U+00FF 
        // and a byte in the range 0x00-0xFF (which is the range that can hit the network). 
        // The Latin-1 encoding (ISO-88591-1) (GetEncoding(28591)) works for byte[] to string, but is a little slow.
        // It doesn't work for string -> byte[] because of best-fit-mapping problems. 
        internal static class HeaderEncoding {

Comment: Excuse me, RFC are long to read. Does the Location have the space character to be escaped or not? I saw some website to redirect to smth like "/my photo.jpg" and that caused some exception deep in stdlib URI module of my language so I've added `URI.escape`. My pull request passed existing tests and was accepted but now I realized that escaping applied two times goes wrong. So does the space character have to be escaped and that website was doing redirect wrong? Or is space character allowed and so it was a stdlib fault?

Comment: Maybe I should catch that exception and call the `URI.escape` only in that case. Or maybe I should always try to unescape once and then escape again? Or maybe Location is never escaped so my patch was correct and I don't have to worry.

Answer (score 1):

I've [reported this a bug](http://uservoice.com/a/iaJKb) over at bit.ly's support forum.  They should be responding with a legal RFC 1630 URI in the ASCII character set (no octets with the high-bit set).

Comment: Hi. I'm an engineer at bitly. We have been slowly rolling out changes to percent escape URL's in redirects so they are ascii only, and currently do that conditionally for some browsers (*cough* IE). Thanks for your feedback though; we should be rolling that out more widely soon.

Comment: Can you do it for my crawler's UA too?

Comment: Hey @Jehiah, are you guys going to fix this?  It's still serving incorrectly