# how to work around encoding problems in redirects

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

A website I try to scrape seems to have an encoding problem. The pages state, that they are encoded in utf-8, but if I try to scrape them and fetch the html source using requests, the redirect adress contains an encoding, that is not utf-8.
Browsers seem to be tolerant, so they fix this automatically, but the python requests package runs into an exception.

My code looks like this:

```
res= rq.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
```

This runs into an exception when trying to decode the redirect string in the following code (hidden somewhere in the requests package):

```
string.decode(encoding)
```

where string is the redirect string and encoding is 'utf8':

```
string= b'/aktien/herm\xe8s-aktie'
```

I found out, that the encoding in fact is encoded in something like 'Windows-1252'. Actually the redirect should go on '/aktien/herm%C3%A8s-aktie'.

Now my question: how can I either get requests to be more tolerant about such encoding bugs (like the browsers), or how can I alternatively pass an encoding?

I searched for encoding settings, but what I saw so far, requests always does that automatically based on the result.

Btw. the result page of the redirect starts with (it really states to be utf-8)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: For obvious reasons, I woud prefer not to add the original url in the posting above (I think it is probably also not necessary). If you want to check things, or try out the code, you can access it here: https://pastebin.com/EBfA1pm7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hooks=` parameter in `requests.get()` method and explicitly urlencode the `Location` HTTP header. For example:

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse

url = "<YOUR URL FROM EXAMPLE>"


def response_hook(hook_data, **kwargs):
    if "Location" in hook_data.headers:
        hook_data.headers["Location"] = urllib.parse.quote(
            hook_data.headers["Location"]
        )


res = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, hooks={"response": response_hook})
print(res.url)
```

Prints:

```
https://.../herm%C3%A8s-aktie
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, great, that seems to solve the problem. What do you think about this. Was it a bug on server side (improper encoding?), or do you think, that the requests package does not handle the kind of response correclty?

Comment: @jottbe I'd think it's the server's bug. The `Location` header should be in plain ASCII, not in UTF/Other encoding. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654207/what-charset-should-be-used-for-a-location-header-in-a-301-response

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your explanation.